# Different version of approximation complexity and algorithm for densest-k-subgraph problem

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness

In the densest-k-subgraph problem, we are given a graph $G =(V,E)$ and $k$, and we are asked to find a set $S \in V$ of vertices to maximize the number of edges in the induced graph of $S$, i.e. $|Ind[S]|$.

Let the optimal solution be $S^*$, the approximation problem finds another $S$ with size $k$ and the approximation ratio $\alpha$ means $|Ind[S]| = \frac{1}{\alpha} |Ind[S^*]|$. I have learned that there is an $n^{1/4 +\epsilon}$ approximation algorithm.

However，I want a different version of approximation: a $\beta-$approximation algorithm should return a vertices set $S$ of size $\beta\cdot k$ and $|Ind[S]| \ge |Ind[S*]|$.

I want to know if there are approximation algorithm for densest-k-subgraph under this definition of approximation, and some results on the hardness of approximation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The version you mention is also considered. It is known that a $\beta$-approximation for  your problem implies a $\beta^2$-approximation for the original version via a simple argument.

Comment: The phrase to search for is "Smallest m-Edge Subgraph" or similar. It has a $n^{3-2\sqrt{2}+\epsilon} \approx n^{.172+\epsilon}$ approximation, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0144.pdf . The statement of the result is in Corollary 6.2. The derivation uses basically the same log-density framework as does the $n^{1/4-\epsilon}$ algorithm for DkS, so an improvement in either result will likely imply something for the other.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information !